# jQuery .off (unbind) not working after event.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, jquery

The question has not yet been answered with a solution but it still not working for me.

The problem is that I want do disable links if a save button is not clicked (trying to override the onbeforeunload function).

My page structure looks like this :

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a class="noclic" href="..."></a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="noclic" href="..."></a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="noclic" href="..."></a>
    </li>
</ul>
<button type="button" class="save">Save</button>
<form>...</form>
<button type="button" class="save">Save</button>
```

And here's my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.noclic').on('click', function (e) {
        //(I also display a confirm modal)
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        console.log("locked");
    });
    $('.save').click(function () {
        $('.noclic').off('click');
        console.log("unlocked");
    });
});
```

When I click on the nav links, the console shows the "locked" message.
But when the button is clicked, the "unlocked" console shows quickly before vanishing, and the event.preventDefault is still running.

What am I doing wrong ?!

Comment: `class="save"` - it is class not id so `$('.save')`

Comment: In addition, `<button>` elements default to submit buttons. Use `<button type="button">` instead to prevent the page from reloading.

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks for your reply, I mistaken while writing my example !

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I've tried changing the button type before reading your message, thanks for that anyway.
It seems that it's the .off that causes page reload, because <type="button"> should not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues
1) Your buttons are "submit" buttons, thus, when you click, the page is reloaded. You have to change them to

```
<button type="button">
```

2) Your buttons have class "save" but you use $( "#save" ) instead of $( ".save" ) to reference them